# html form posts to different php file specified in action?

Tags: php, html

i have a few divs on my index page, though i am having problems with sending form data i have in a div i am using for a suggestion box.

The suggestion box by itself works fine, it sends the data to thankyou.php (located in root directory) which inserts the data in the database and displays a thank you message before it redirects back to the index page. But as soon as i require two php files(php/login.php, php/register.php) in a separate div that displays a login and register panel the form no longer sends the data to thankyou.php, but tries to send it to /login.php in the root directory where the file doesn't even exist and i have no idea why. It also messes up the position of the textarea and submit button when i require the two files. here is the code.

```
<!-- login and register div-->
    <div id="loginRegister" style="display:none;">
        <h1> Login | Register </h1>
        <hr />

        <table>
         <tr>
          <td><?php require_once('php/login.php');?></td>   
          <td><?php require_once('php/register.php');?></td>
         </tr>
         </table>

         <p id="closeLoginregister" style="float:right;margin:10px;">Close</p>
    </div>

    <!-- marketing div -->
    <div id="marketing">

        <div style="position:relative;left:20px;top: 20px; display:inline-block">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/twitter" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false"></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"></a>
        </div>

        <!-- suggestion box form -->
        <form action="thankyou.php" method="post">
          <textarea id="suggestion" name="suggestion_text" placeholder="Enter suggestion here.." width="500px" cols="40" rows="5" ></textarea>
          <input type="hidden" name="message" value="Thank you, your suggestion has been sent!">
          <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Send" id="submit">
        </form>



        <img id="suggestionBox" src="images/suggestionbox.png" alt="stamp">


    </div>
```

Why would it be doing this?

Comment: Try using absolute url in all form action.

Comment: What does `php/login.php` and `php/register.php` look like? Do you have a form in either of those that has `login.php ` as the action? If you are missing the closing `</form>` tag, than it will nest your suggestion form into that form.

Comment: Ahh yes, Sean, it was exactly that! I feel stupid now. Thank you very much.